cómo segmentar para una subcategoría de datos y no para las demás cuando están en el mismo objeto power bi
por favor necesito ayuda con esto. Tengo una tabla con las tareas y su estado, las tareas completadas tienen fecha de finalización. Necesito que una página tenga un segmentador que tome la fecha de cierre (o alguna forma calculada) y esto filtre las completadas para esta fecha pero deje solas las otras que no tienen fecha. No es con las interacciones porque los datos están en el mismo objeto (tabla o gráfico): Ejemplo en la imagen, tabla inicial con estado, un segmento, una tabla con lo que excluye, etc, resultados. Ahora si pongo eso, cuando muevo el filtro de fecha de fecha mínima excluye las que no tienen fecha. Ya intenté generar una columna que me traiga la fecha máxima de cierre para ponérsela a los que no la tienen y así siempre estoy usando esta columna como segmentador, pero este máximo queda estático y no dinámico.
ff = VAR MaxAllDate = CALCULATE(Max('POA 2024'[Fecha de cierre]), ALL('POA 2024')) 
VAR HasClosingDate = NOT(ISBLANK('POA 2024'[Fecha de cierre])) 
RETURN 
IF(HasClosingDate, ' POA 2024'[Fecha de cierre], MaxAllDate)  

o
ff = VARMaxAllDate = CALCULATE(Max('POA 2024'[Fecha de cierre]), ALLselected('POA 2024'[Fecha de cierre])) 
VAR HasClosingDate = NOT(IS[

]1
